# Which preposition should precede "schooling": at or in?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Which preposition precedes the noun "schooling" Is it

> 1. medium of instruction at schooling

or

> 2. medium of instruction in schooling.

Comment: Do not use _at_ - 'schooling' isn't a place.

Answer (score 1):

Q.

> **Which preposition precedes the noun "schooling"** Is it 1.medium of instruction at schooling or 2.medium of instruction in schooling.

---

A. **OF**

> **the medium of instruction of schooling** Ref [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medium_of_instruction)

> If the first language of students is different from the official language, it may be used as the medium of instruction for part or all **of schooling**.

We would use in if you were using the word school or schools.

> What should be the medium of instruction in schools?